# Print the match from file1 contains lines from file 2

Tags: linux

i am  linux command newbie, help would be appreciated.

```
File 1:
1:aaa@email.com:name1
2:bbb@email.com:name2
3:ccc@email.com:name3
4:ddd@email.com:name4
....

File 2:
bbb@email.com
ddd@email.com
.....

File 3: should print
2:bbb@email.com:name2
4:ddd@email.com:name4
...
```

I want to print the match from file one match the line in file 2.

Answer (score 0):

If the patterns are one per line, you can use grep.

```
grep -w -F -f file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: I think you probably want `grep -w -f file2 file1` (because if file2 had b@email.com, then bbb@email.com and bb@email.com and foob@email.com would match).

Comment: @Nirk I figured it would either be `-w` or `-F`, I always forget. Thanks.

Comment: you need both: `grep -w -F -f file2 file1 > file3`. Though there still could be false positives.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Cool thank you. I'm not near a terminal so I couldn't test it.

Comment: you can test it online. Here's [an example that shows a false positive](http://ideone.com/XGQl76)